# How can I implement Material Date Range Picker correctly?

Tags: android, date, android-datepicker

I am implementing Date Range Picker with this material library.

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05"
```

And this is what I implemented.

```
btn_calendar.setOnClickListener {
    val builder = MaterialDatePicker
        .Builder
        .dateRangePicker()
        .setTheme(R.style.DatePickerTheme)
//                .setTitleText("Select dates")
//                .build()

    val now = Calendar.getInstance()

    val picker = builder.build()
    builder.setSelection(androidx.core.util.Pair(now.timeInMillis, now.timeInMillis))
    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())

    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Date String = ${picker.headerText}::  Date epoch values::${it.first}:: to :: ${it.second}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And the style is:

```
<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents"/>
```

However, it shows weird looking view. How can I fix this? I want dialog

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Material Components Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) as app theme.
In any case if you are using:

```
.setTheme(R.style.DatePickerTheme)
```

you should define a theme like:

```
  <style name="DatePickerTheme"
           parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar" >
       ....
  </style>
```